# Multiple same ID's same page with jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Before I start, I do understand that having the same ID one more than one element on one page is invalid but it's the best method I've come up with for dealing with this problem...

I have several generated tables on one page, each row of each table can be edited or removed with buttons per row.  It's these buttons which I attach the ID so I can easily know what the ID of the object I'm editing/deleting is.  This works well when saving to the database but causes a problem when I try to dynamically update the table row using JQuery.

Here's an example of the code from the edit button dialog save function:

```
//find the edit button so we can get the row this item is in
var editButton = $("#theTable").add("editButtonClass").add("#"+id);
var row = editButton.parents('tr:first');
//update the current page with new row data
row.find(":eq(0)").text(name);
row.find(":eq(1)").text(value);
```

This works fine if there is only one table on the page, but as there are many tables, some of which the buttons end up with the same IDs (I use auto increment in my db tables), this function will update the first row it finds with the ID, effectively ignoring my $("theTable").add("editButtonClass") selector!

Any ideas on this would be most helpful!

---

Info:  I have also used the following selector to get the edit button and id, which works with one table but not with multiple tables with the same id:

```
var findButtonStr = "#" + id + ", editButtonClass";
var editButton = $(findButtonStr);
var row = editButton.parent().parent();
```

---

An example of what the generated table might look like:

```
<table id="theTable">
  <tr><td>name</td><td>value</td><td><a id="1" class="editButtonClass">Edit</a> / <a id="1" class="deleteButtonClass">Delete</a></td></tr>
  <tr><td>name</td><td>value</td><td><a id="2" class="editButtonClass">Edit</a> / <a id="2" class="deleteButtonClass">Delete</a></td></tr>
</table>
```

I might have several tables like this on one page which means there will be several rows with buttons that have the same id.

---

EDIT:  Thanks for the downvote!  Please, if you have an issue with the question then tell me and I will fix it.

Comment: Aside from duplicated ids.. shouldn't it be addClass() not add()?

Comment: Duplicating ids is never a good idea

Comment: If you have more than one elements with the same ID, it's simply **bad**. There is no *workaround* for that. You break a basic HTML rule. Why can't you use classes on those tables?

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  I've seen many solutions online to update rows of tables by attaching the id to the button.  I guess I could just use a class instead!

Comment: Your code is pretty bad BTW. In HTML, you would just do class="editButtonClass". No dot is needed. I think you're getting downvoted because your HTML and jQuery are generally a mess.

Comment: TBH that's not my actual code, just a representation of it!  I tried to take out the complexities of what i'm actually doing and so introduced some typos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the buttons for edit/delete are contained within the row you want to perform actions on, why not just use `$(this)` within the button click event??

```
$('.editButtonClass .deleteButtonClass').click(function() {
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr');

    $(document).data('editRow', $row);
    // call dialog, have the dialog save code do this:
    //    var $row = $(document).data('editRow');
    // and then perform operations on $row
});
```

---

EDIT:

Get rid of the leading dot in your classes in your HTML code. `class="editButtonClass"` is what you want. Follow proper syntax!

Comment: His classes have a dot. To select them you must use \\.editButtonClass

Comment: @Nicola His classes should not have a dot in front. It's bad, convention-wise. But I'll add a note in my answer.

Comment: The dot is a typo in my example code... I don't have the dot in my actual code.

Comment: @peacemaker Ok, my answer assumes you have dots in the classes, take off '\\.' from my code to make it work!

Comment: I use the $(this) in the click method.  The click method then populates a Jquery UI dialog and opens it.  The save function of that dialog is where i wish to update the table, therefore I cannot use the $(this) but instead must use selectors similar to above.

Comment: Ah!  A good solution, saving the actual row before the dialog.  Nice.

Answer (score 0):

in Jquery this selector

```
 $("#theTable").add(".editButtonClass")
```

Always return only the first object with that id. if you need to select more than one object. you must use other selectors. If you show us your full markup we might help you better

EDIT - looking at your markup this is what you need, i think

```
$('.\\.editButtonClass').click(function(){
   var name = $(this).closest('tr').find(":eq(0)");
    var value = $(this).closest('tr').find(":eq(1)");
   alert(name.html());  
   alert(value.html());
});
```

look at the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/UJGeP/1/ (name and value are the td you need, i alert their value to show that the correct td has been chosen)

Comment: I've added my markup above.  As you can see, doing this selector will give me all the edit buttons.  This is why I also use .add("#"+id) because I need the specific edit button.

Comment: I dont understand exactly what you need to get! :). When you click the edit button what do you want to get?The relative name and value?

Comment: I need the row that the button is in so I can update the cells with the new data :)

Comment: See my comment above.  I use the $(this) in the click function ok and this is used to save the data to my DB.  However, click opens a UI dialog and it's that dialog save function where I need to selector to get the edit button, so I can't use $(this).

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the duplicates, I´m pretty sure that ID's cannot begin with a number either.

Anyway, why don´t you just use the [`data`](http://docs.jquery.com/Data) attribute, that seems the most appropriate in this case as you are not using it for any styling anyway.

Comment: Interestingly I was just reading about that and think it might be the way to go.  Thanks!

Comment: But you cannot use a selector to pick elements based on their data, as far as I know.

Comment: So I can't do something like:  $("#theTable").add(".editButton").attr("data")   ?

Comment: @peacemaker No, that will not work. See my answer, this should work for you.

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack No, but you can easily store the clicked row in a temporary variable and as far as I can see that´s all that´s needed here.